# Angular Drag and drop is not working if using *ngFor in cdkDropList

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular-material2

I was tried to using angular material drag and drop and I was looping through `cdkDropList` container. I'm not able to drag the items from Catalogue to (to do )list. If I'm not using any loop then it's working fine.

Here is my [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iexh17?file=package.json)

I tried without loop that is working fine

```html
<div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList"  [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[done]" [id]="item"
  class="column-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" 
  <div class="column-box" [ngClass]="[(item.Name=='R') ?'Red':'',(item.Name=='G') ?'Green':'',(item.Name=='B') ?
  'Blue':'',(item.Name=='Y') ?'Yellow':'',(item.Name=='O') ?'Orange':'']" *ngFor="let item of items3" cdkDrag cdkDragLockAxis="y">
    {{item.Name}}</div>
</div>
```

but if I'm adding this `*ngFor` it's not working

```html
<div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList"  [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[done]" [id]="item"
  class="column-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" *ngFor="let item of signalContainer">
  <div class="column-box" [ngClass]="[(item.Name=='R') ?'Red':'',(item.Name=='G') ?'Green':'',(item.Name=='B') ?
  'Blue':'',(item.Name=='Y') ?'Yellow':'',(item.Name=='O') ?'Orange':'']" *ngFor="let item of items3" cdkDrag cdkDragLockAxis="y">
    {{item.Name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**COMPONENT.TS**

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

    @Component({
      selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example',
      templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css'],
    })
    export class CdkDragDropConnectedSortingExample {

    initialSkeleton = new Array(5);
      done = [
        'A','B','C','D','E'
      ];

      drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          debugger;
         moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
          event.container.data[event.currentIndex] =  event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
        }

      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="example-container">
        <h2>To do</h2>
        <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="initialSkeleton" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]" class="example-list"
         (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of initialSkeleton" cdkDrag>
             <div class="child" >{{item }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="example-container">
        <h2>Done</h2>
        <div cdkDropList #doneList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="done" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]" class="example-list"
         (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've modified the code now you will be able to  drag and drop items in the for loop. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks it's worked fine.but it's adding one extra div.I'm trying to work on that.Once I'm done I'll Post.

Comment: @Ramya What is the key part that makes it work in a for loop?